# C# ASP.NET Core string expression in a taghelper property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razorengine, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

In my tag helper I declared a property like this:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("tr", TagStructure = TagStructure.NormalOrSelfClosing)]
public class EditTableTRTag : TagHelper
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("edit-rowId")]
    public Object RowId { get; set; }
}
```

In the process method I check if it is a null or not, then apply the `.ToString()` to generate a `data-row-id="..."` attribute from its value:

```
public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    if (RowId != null && IsTotalRow==false) 
        output.Attributes.Add("data-row-id", RowId.ToString());
}
```

In the `.cshtml` I have a local Int32 value to help generating incremental row ID expressions.

```
@{ var i = 0; }
@foreach(....)
{
   <tr edit-rowId="@(i)_th_row" ...
   ...
}
```

The above code does not seem to work:

> Error CS0118: 'rowid' is a variable but it is used like a type
> Error CS0103: The name '_th_row' does not exist in the current context

The following code does not throw any compile-time error:

```
<tr data-row-id="@(i)_th_row" ...
```

I wonder why it is, and what is the solution?

Note: I declared the property as `Object` not `String` for a reason: I want to use as the following (where `MyEnum` is an enum):

```
<tr edit-rowId="@MyEnum.MyOption1"
```

But: when I changed the property type from `Object` to `String`, the compile-time error disappeared. Still don't know how to keep the property type as `Object` and avoid the compile-time error.

Comment: I use your code: Object and `<tr edit-rowId="11"></tr>` I don't meet the error. If you can provide a minimal reproducible example, we're much more likely to be able to help you. Besides, you may want to search something about Binding to complex properties.

Comment: When you add a fix value "11" - its another use case. In my example the "@(i)_th_row" causes the razor compile error against the tagHelper.

Comment: How you define the `_th_row` ?

Comment: it a string literal. the rowid looks as "1_th_row"